# Is it possible to create an empty Git repository on Visual Studio Online using the command line?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a number of local git repositories.  I'd like to set the remote origin to Visual Studio Online and push them there for backup.  If the empty repository exists on VS online this is easy, but, is there a command line way to create the empty repository? Or is the only way from the web interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use the [Visual Studio Team Services REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1), using one of the [client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1#client-libraries) directly from command line.
[`Microsoft/vsts-python-api`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-python-api) for instance allows you to script the command and call that wrapper script.

It has a [Git section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/?view=vsts-rest-4.1) which includes [adding a repository to a project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/repositories/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1).

> Sample Request HTTP
>
> ```
> POST https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=4.1
> ```
>
> Request Body
>
> ```
> JSON
> ```

```
{
  "name": "AnotherRepository",
  "project": {
    "id": "6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c"
  }
}
```

---

The [OP Chasler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10119/chasler) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51733875/is-it-possible-to-create-an-empty-git-repository-on-visual-studio-online-using-t/51734135#comment90677716_51734135):

> This worked after creating alternate credentials for VSTS.

```
curl -u username@live.com:AlternateCredentials -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -X POST \
  -d "{\"name\": \"AnotherRepository\",\"project\": {\"id\": \"QUID that matches projectName in url following\"}}" \
  https://AccountName.visualstudio.com/projectName/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=4.1
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try this out and accept answer if it works.  I hope to get back to this in the next couple of days.

Comment: @VonC.  Thanks.  This worked after creating alternate credentials for VSTS.

`curl -u username@live.com:AlternateCredentials -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"name\": \"AnotherRepository\",\"project\": {\"id\": \"QUID that matches projectName in url following\"}}"  https://AccountName.visualstudio.com/projectName/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=4.1`

@JackZhai-MSFT

Comment: @Chasler Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @Chasler, Thanks for sharing your solution here, as VonC shared it as the answer, would you mind marking it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issue, and we could close this case. Have a nice day:)